# Keras CNN always predicts same class

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

EDIT: it seems like I did not even run the model for enough epochs, so I will try that out and return with my results

I am trying to create a CNN that classifies 3D brain images. However, the CNN program always predict the same class when I run it and am not sure what other methods I can do to prevent this. I have searched up this problem with many plausible solutions, but they did not work

So far, I have tried:

- Decreasing the learning rate
- Normalize the data to [0, 1]
- Change optimizers
- Only use sigmoid and binary_crossentropy
- Add/remove dropout layers
- Changed into a simpler CNN model
- Balance the dataset
- Added augmented data using a custom 3D imagedatagenerator()

  - Link: https://github.com/dhuy228/augmented-volumetric-image-generator

For context, I am classifying between two groups. The amount of images I am using is a total of 200 3D brain images (about 100 for each category). To increase my training size, I used a custom data augmentation I found from github

Looking at the learning curve, the accuracy and loss rates are completely random. Some runs they would be decreasing, some increasing, and some fluctuating within a range

Any help would be appreciated!

```
import os
import csv
import tensorflow as tf  # 2.0
import nibabel as nib
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, LabelEncoder
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Conv3D, MaxPooling3D, Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten 
from keras.layers import Input, concatenate
from keras import optimizers
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from augmentedvolumetricimagegenerator.generator import customImageDataGenerator
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping


# Administrative items
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

# Where the file is located
path = r'C:\Users\jesse\OneDrive\Desktop\Research\PD\decline'
folder = os.listdir(path)

target_size = (96, 96, 96)


# creating x - converting images to array
def read_image(path, folder):
    mri = []
    for i in range(len(folder)):
        files = os.listdir(path + '\\' + folder[i])
        for j in range(len(files)):
            image = np.array(nib.load(path + '\\' + folder[i] + '\\' + files[j]).get_fdata())
            image = np.resize(image, target_size)
            image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=3)
            image /= 255.
            mri.append(image)
    return mri

# creating y - one hot encoder
def create_y():
    excel_file = r'C:\Users\jesse\OneDrive\Desktop\Research\PD\decline_label.xlsx'
    excel_read = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
    excel_array = np.array(excel_read['Label'])
    label = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(excel_array)
    label = label.reshape(len(label), 1)
    onehot = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False).fit_transform(label)
    return onehot

# Splitting image train/test
x = np.asarray(read_image(path, folder))
y = np.asarray(create_y())
x_split, x_test, y_split, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=.2, stratify=y)
x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x_split, y_split, test_size=.25, stratify=y_split)
print(x_train.shape, x_val.shape, x_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_val.shape, y_test.shape)


batch_size = 10
num_classes = len(folder)

inputs = Input((96, 96, 96, 1))
conv1 = Conv3D(32, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu')(inputs)
conv1 = Conv3D(32, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu')(conv1)
pool1 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(conv1)
drop1 = Dropout(0.5)(pool1)

conv2 = Conv3D(64, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu')(drop1)
conv2 = Conv3D(64, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu')(conv2)
pool2 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(conv2)
drop2 = Dropout(0.5)(pool2)

conv3 = Conv3D(128, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu')(drop2)
conv3 = Conv3D(128, [3, 3, 3], padding='same', activation='relu')(conv3)
pool3 = MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2), padding='same')(conv3)
drop3 = Dropout(0.5)(pool3)

flat1 = Flatten()(drop3)
dense1 = Dense(128, activation='relu')(flat1)
drop5 = Dropout(0.5)(dense1)
dense2 = Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid')(drop5)

model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[dense2])

opt = optimizers.Adagrad(lr=1e-5)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])


train_datagen = customImageDataGenerator(
                                         horizontal_flip=True
                                        )

val_datagen = customImageDataGenerator()

training_set = train_datagen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size)

validation_set = val_datagen.flow(x_val, y_val, batch_size=batch_size)


callbacks = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3)

history = model.fit_generator(training_set,
                    steps_per_epoch = 10,
                    epochs = 20,
                    validation_steps = 5,
                    callbacks = [callbacks],
                    validation_data = validation_set)

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=batch_size)
print(score)


y_pred = model.predict(x_test, batch_size=batch_size)
y_test = np.argmax(y_test, axis=1)
y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
confusion = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
map = sns.heatmap(confusion, annot=True)
print(map)


acc = history.history['accuracy']
val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']
loss = history.history['loss']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(acc)
plt.plot(val_acc)
plt.ylabel('accuracy')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='best')
plt.title('Accuracy')

plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(loss)
plt.plot(val_loss)
plt.ylabel('loss')
plt.xlabel('epoch')
plt.legend(['train', 'test'], loc='best')
plt.title('Loss')
```

You can find the outputs here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FF13P.jpg

Comment: Can you share the output log, model.summary, and the visualizations as well?

Comment: The layer `dense2` should have only 1 neuron, not `num_classes`. Also you are using too much dropout. And back to back convolution is just a waste of computation.

Comment: @AbhiramSatputé I have edited the question with the outputs that you can find here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FF13P.jpg

Answer (score 1):

It is kind of hard to help without the dataset itself. Though one or two things I would test:

- I find the ReLU activation inappropriate for Dense layer, which could lead to the mono-class prediction. Try replacing the relu from your Dense(128) layer by something else (sigmoid, tanh)
- Dropout is not really appropriate for images in general, you might want to look at [DropBlock](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.12890)
- Initial learning rate is pretty low, I would start with something between 1e-3 or 1e-4
- Stupid thing that happened to me way too often: have you visualize the image / label combinaison to make sure each image has the right label?

Again, not sure it will fix everything, but I hope it might help!

Comment: Thank you for your input, after trying your suggestions I have seen that 1. the dense(128) layer's activation does not seem to impact the accuracy in any way unfortunately. 2. I have removed the dropouts which will hopefully improve the model, however it seems like it is not enough. 3. you are correct, and I have adjusted the learning rate appropriately, hopefully it will not overfit. 4. I label each image using an excel file in the order of the files that read_images(path, folder) will read it, hoping that it will combine when I train_test_split it. Not sure what how else I can check. Thanks!

Comment: Let me get back to you and see how things go

Answer (score 1):

This could be any number of things, but it is possible that the misbehaviour is being caused by the data itself.

Just from looking at the code, it seems like you haven't normalized the testing data before calling `model.predict` or `model.evaluate` in the same way as you have done for the training and validation data.

I had a similar problem once and it turned out this was the cause. As a quick test you can just rescale the test data and see if that helps.

Comment: You are correct, I did not realize that mistake until now, thank you. I have edited the question with the correct normalization for all images, however while I believe it will help in the future, it does not currently solve the problem and the model still predicts a single class, unfortunately